# Linux: why colon (:) is removed from the file name when using uuencode?

Tags: linux, email, uuencode

I am trying to e-mail a file containing colon (:) character in the name:

```
my_attachment_name=some_file_with_:_in_the_name.txt
uuencode "${my_attachment_name}" "`basename \"${my_attachment_name}\"`"
     | mail -s "My Report ..." my_email@xyz.com
```

But, when I receive the e-mail, I see ":" has been removed from the file name.

```
some_file_with__in_the_name.txt
```

How can I fixed it?

Thanks.

Comment: There are many different `mail` implementations, which one is this?

Comment: @mata no idea. how can I know?

Comment: that depends on your linux distribution, check your package manager which mail-related packages are installed...

Answer (score 0):

You might try using uuencode with "--encode-file-name".  However, here, I'm seeing:

```
$ uuencode foo:bar.txt foo:bar.txt
begin 664 foo:bar.txt
#:&D*
`
end
```

which is exactly what I'd want in the "begin" line.

In contrast:

```
$ uuencode --encode-file-name foo:bar.txt foo:bar.txt
begin-encoded 664 Zm9vOmJhci50eHQ=
#:&D*
`
end
```

uudecode doesn't require any options to be able to reconstruct foo:bar.txt from Zm9vOmJhci50eHQ= on my computer.

Check the raw content of your email too, it's possible the email client is being stupid.  A DOS bias, for example, could make an email client ditch colons.

Comment: : was also the directory separator on classic Mac OS. It may be getting stripped because it's considered generally unportable in file names.

Comment: Makes sense - the idea of only banning what *has* to be banned from a filename is pretty Unixy (Linux, OS X) - "/" and NUL.